# How is this number sequence built up and how does it continue?

Tags: number-sequence

Can you work out how this number sequence is built up? Can you work out how it continues?

> 1, 1, 2, 4, 8, 20, 60, 240, 1500, .......

*Hint 1*

> this is a mathematical puzzle

*Hint 2*

> It does not involve complicated mathematics

*From time to time hints will be updated.*

*Note: this sequence cannot be found in [The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](https://oeis.org/)*

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The next number is

> 16140

Following this pattern, given the sequence is $a_n$

> $a_n = a_{n-1} + a_{n-2} \cdot (a_{n-3} + 1)$
>  Example:  60 = 20 + 8 * (4 + 1)

Comment: Great job, well done. -- The solution you have is correct, but expressed ever so slightly differently to the way I had in mind, but it is equivalent. The way I put it together was $a_n = a_{n-1} + a_{n-2} + a_{n-2}.a_{n-3}$. So Well done, congratulations.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

It seems like I was way off on the pattern I was trying to track. Seems like this is a neat coincidence though.

Comment: What does this mean? I'm confused.

Comment: looks interesting, but I don't understand this either - can you explain a bit more?

Comment: It's the distances between the first point and all the other points in the sequence plotted as (x,y) where x = 1, 2, 3. . . and y = the sequence. It seems like distance = y(rounded to the closest even number)

Comment: What you effectively have shown there is that $$Lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{(X_n - 1)^2 + (Y_n - 1)^2} \to Y_n$$.  Which is another way of saying Y grows much faster than x... or by more than 1 per term.

Answer (score 2):

Obligatory nth order polynomial:

> $$f(x) = \frac{5}{384}x^8-\frac{4597}{10080}x^7+\frac{19471}{2880}x^6 - \frac{19831}{360}x^5+\frac{308935}{1152}x^4-\frac{1141669}{1440}x^3+\frac{1982957}{1440}x^2-\frac{354937}{280}+465$$

Predicted next five values:

> 8116, 33619, 112289, 318913, 800021

Comment: I dislike people reflexively pointing out that there is always an nth-order polynomial (or spline) that fits n arbitrary points. Anyway the spirit of this question forbade it: **"It does not involve complicated mathematics"** (yeah you could try to argue that nth-order interpolation doesn't). If the OP wanted to be more lawyerly they could have said "the answer has < n characters and only requires the four elementary operations".

Comment: *"If one plugs it into the given numbers, they all match... the next fives values are [given integers]"* I doubt it does, it looks like you're doing rounding, most of your subterms aren't even integers.

Comment: Ugh, freaking datatypes. I guess I should've done it by hand. Anyways, I've cleaned up the post after realizing how abrasive it was.

Comment: Your post was perfectly fine, just without the first sentence, also noting that in general that f(n) will give non-integer values. Curious which language you used, Python or what?

Comment: Interesting solution - sorry not correct, but +1 for the polynomial fitting

Comment: @smci nah, I've got a TI-Nspire CX CAS  that I use for stuff like this. Because it doesn't have to bend over for the root compiler like sympy does, it's easier to use. Otherwise, I'd totally use sympy, yeah.